# User hasMany Posts - Lithium MongoDB relationship

Tags: php, php-mongodb, lithium

I'm just trying out the simplest of the examples for hasMany relations where User hasMany Posts. A user_id is hardwired in view code when saving posts for testing.

Questions:

1. Are relationships supported for Lithium 0.11 release for document database/mongodb?
2. The controller is expected to return the posts belonging to the user but none is returned
3. Assuming $users returned the joined data from posts, is $user->posts the correct way of accessing it?

   ```
   class PostsController extends \lithium\action\Controller {      
   public function index() {
   $posts = Posts::find('all', array('with' => 'Users'));        
   $users = Users::find('all',array('with' => 'Posts'));        
   return compact('posts','users');      
   }
   public function add() {
       $success = false;
       if ($this->request->data) {
           $post = Posts::create($this->request->data);
           $success = $post->save();
       }
       return compact('success');
   }
   ```

The model classes:

```
    class Posts extends \lithium\data\Model {
    public $belongsTo = array('Users' => array(
                                            'key'=>'user_id'));
}

    class Users extends \lithium\data\Model {
    public $hasMany = array('Posts');

}
```

The Index View to print out the posts and also the users with the posts belonging to them.

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
<article>
    <h1><?=$post->title ?></h1>
    <p><?=$post->body ?></p>
    <p><?=$post->user_id ?></p>
</article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<hr/> <hr/>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
<article>
    <h1><?=$user->name ?></h1>
    <p><?=$user->_id ?></p>
    <p><?=$user->posts ?></p>
</article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Currently, MongoDB relationships aren't supported in Lithium, however it's pretty trivial to write your own accessors.

Comment: @NateAbele Yup..coded them now. Any hints as to by when shall the relationships for MongoDB be supported in Lithium?

Comment: @NateAbele Are relationships implemented in newer releases (if any!)

Comment: As soon as I have the time (not yet).

Comment: Hey Niles Kale and Nate Abele I am trying to do the same thing. Were you able to code that? my relations are not working in mongodb as well. Any hints on how to fix that would be a great help. Thanks